# Curve in $\mathbb{R}^n$ $(t,f(t))$ bi-regular if and only if $f''(t)\neq 0$

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, parametrization

> Let $f:\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ be a function such that $f\in\mathcal{C}^{\infty}(I)$. Evaluate the curvature of $\gamma(t):=(t,f(t))$ and prove that $\gamma$ is biregular if and only if $f''(t)\neq 0$, $\forall t\in I$.

I know that the curvature is

$$k(t):=\frac{\mid\mid\gamma '(t)\wedge\gamma '' (t)\mid\mid}{\mid\mid \gamma'(t)\mid\mid^{3}}.$$

But in this case I can't operate with this furmula and I don't know how to proceed. Can someone help me? Thanks before!

Comment: What does biregular mean?

Comment: $\gamma'(t)\wedge\Gamma(t)

Comment: γ'(t)\wedge γ''(t) ≠ 0 for all t

Comment: Where in the world does that definition come from? I've never seen it in my 40+ years as a differential geometer. At any rate, edit your post to show what you've tried. What are $\gamma'(t)$ and $\gamma''(t)$? What is their wedge product?

Comment: Sorry, I know that the vectorial product is defined only on $\mathbb{R}^{3}$. It''s biregular if the curvature is never 0. In the case $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ the condiction is equivalent to say what I wrote. Anyway, I don't know how to evaluate the curvature of a curve in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, at the lessons the professor show us only curves in the plain and in the space. Maybe the trace is wrong, I don't know. Do you know if there is a a definition of curvature in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

Comment: The definition in $\Bbb R^n$ is the same as the usual one. Parametrize by arclength (speed $1$), and then take the length of the second derivative. The formula you've given is derived from this, using the chain rule. Do you know what exterior product is in higher dimensions? If not, you need to talk with your professor.